# How are parameters in graphical models learnt?

Tags: references, graphical-model, training-error

This is a request of a good reference. I wanted to have a better understanding of graphical models and I am reading "Pattern recognition and machine learning" of Bishop. chap. 8 (Graphical Models).

It spends a long time talking about Bayesian nets and markov random fields, as a way to build "structured" density functions for multidimensional random variables. Than it discusses a lot inference algorithms, like sum-product algorithm, etc. . Inference algorithms are very useful to read/compute expectation values/correlations/... out of the fitted density once the parameters of the Bayesian Nets or of the markov random fields are fixed.

But the book does not say much about how one learns the parameters. Is there a standard way to do this for graphical models ? Is there a good  reference ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Depends largely on the type of graphical model. For example, in [SEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling), the parameters are estimated by expectation maximization, whereas in (penalized) covariance matrix inversion, the edges can be learned by block-coordinate descent (this is what [`glasso`](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/glasso-bio.pdf) uses), or even by MCMC (this is what [`BDgraph`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BDgraph/vignettes/vignette.pdf) uses).

Comment: Thank you. Since you cited them, I do not get the difference between graphical models and SEM...

Comment: SEM are just directed graphical models with linear dependences and gaussian distributions?

Comment: Yes, all methods I mentioned estimate the parameters of some sort of graphical model. But how those estimates are obtained differs substantially. If you can give a specific example of what kind of graphical model you are interested in, it is easier for someone familiar with those kinds of graphical models to give an answer.

Comment: I understand now that I should write a different question for each model. I think I will delete this question, since it is too broad, and ask one for a simple Bayes net. Thanks a lot for the moment.